# GridView не правильно отображется в версии 23API

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После обновы мало того ListView линия по стандарту появилась в 1DP, так теперь еще и GridView переделали что аж вон что получается.

Добавил TextView с размерами 50 на 50, а получил совсем иное, вон внизу.

Как сделать чтобы клетка была под картинку

Comment: Используйте RecyclerVIew, например

Comment: И еще нужен xml grid_view_item, хотя бы

Comment: @georgehardcorem, это все фигня, короче

stretchMode если установить в none то будет что надо, но отцентровать теперь ни как... прямо я не знаю геморой.